# Sharing intermediate files between C++ projects?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, object-files

I'm currently trying to figure out whether it is possible for two different native Visual-C++ projects (*that have exactly the same compiler settings*) to share their intermediate files (obj, pch, ...)

An example should help:

This is a normal setup:

```
PROJECTS \ P1 \ p1.vcproj; p1.cpp; ...
              \ Release_Intermediate_Dir \ p1.obj
                                         \ tool1.obj
         \ P2 \ p2.vcproj; p2.cpp; ...
              \ Release_Intermediate_Dir \ p2.obj
                                         \ tool1.obj
         \ COMMON \ tool1.cpp; ...
```

What about this setup:

```
PROJECTS \ P1 \ p1.vcproj (uses: p1.cpp; p1_main.cpp)
              \ p1_test.vcproj (uses: p1.cpp; p1_test.cpp)
              \ Release_Intermediate_Dir \ p1.obj      (used by both projects p1 and test)
                                         \ tool1.obj
                                         \ p1_main.obj (only p1.vcproj)
                                         \ p1_test.obj (only p1_test.vcproj
         \ COMMON \ tool1.cpp; ...
```

**Can I use the *same* intermediate folder for two C++ projects, thereby sharing the `obj` files directly?**

Or will I always need to have an additional static lib project? (As far as I understand, a static lib is [just a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361071/what-is-the-difference-between-lib-and-obj-files-visual-studio-c/1361074#1361074) for `obj` files.)

---

*Why would I want to do this?* Look at this blog post: [Writing Unit Tests in Visual Studio for Native C++](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2010/11/19/writing-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-for-native-c.aspx).

It uses a static lib for the sole purpose of having two different executables (main functions, if you will). (Forget about the managed/CLI stuff.) This means having 3 projects in your solution (having to maintain three projects), when you really only want two projects that share the same code with the same compilation settings but use a different main/startup rigging.

Answer (score 1):

By enforcing the same compilation flags for both projects and making the intermediates of project A prerequisites of project B, you remove all degrees of freedom from B. There is no conceivable possibility to compile B alone, and your link suggests B has no raison d'etre apart from testing A. The easiest and cleanest solution would be to merge the tests from B into A and make the whole thing one project (which it is, frankly).

In automake parlance, you'd declare the unit tests in B as check_PROGRAMS and they'd only be compiled for checking your program. I'm no Visual-C++ expert, but that's the clean solution and should somehow be doable with VC++.

Addendum: To clarify the automake parlance, a project there would for example look like:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libthings-to-test.la libthings-not-tested.la
bin_PROGRAMS = production
check_PROGRAMS = unit_test_a

production_SOURCES = main.cpp
production_LDADD = libthings-to-test.la libthings-not-tested.la
unit_test_a_SOURCES = test.cpp
unit_test_a_LDADD = libthings-to-test.la
libthings_to_test_la_SOURCES = foo.cpp bar.cpp baz.cpp
```

with the whole codebase (production code, common libraries, tests) in one project, i.e. one unit that is configured and distributed wholly and has a single version number attached. When installed by the end user/distributor, a single program `production.exe` would be linked. When compiled with `make all`, the convenience libraries and necessary objects would be compiled in the build directory, and when `make check` is called, the objects only necessary for unit tests are compiled, the production code linked in and the tests are run. Again, I'm sorry I can't translate this into Microsoft Speak.

Comment: Actually it's more of a symmetric relationship IMHO. Both projects share the code. (Same compilation artifacts.) But the linker will link something different for each. I'm not familiar with automake: Could you add a link to the feature you're referring to?

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm afraid the automake manual is not that specific. I've added an example how this would be solved in automake.